# How to yank between vi editors, without quitting one?

Tags: vi, yank

I have opened two vi editors: `vi file1 file2`. Now file1 opens first, and i want to yank some lines from file1 and put it to file 2 **without quitting file1, because more lines can be yanked**, so it is just switching between vi's and yanking.

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can navigate between <strike>two</strike> multiple open files with `:next` and `:previous` (the file has to be saved, it wont allow switching then the current file is "modified").

Comment: Is there any shortened form of `next` and `:previous`?

Comment: @kingsmasher: exactly `:w`. I dont know if `:wnext` is available in "vi" - just try it. But I share @Jay's sentiment: you should upgrade to vim it makes a lot of things easier. edit: The Short form of next is `:n` eventually you can also use `:prev` (not sure if this is vim-only)

Comment: not sure in 'vi' (it's a long time since i used vanilla vi) ... but in vim or gvim since you can 'see' both buffers at the same time you don't need to save to switch focus between them.

Comment: also, i think 'vi' has the 'b' command to switch buffers, i.e., b 1 or b2 (:b 1 or :b 2 in vim)

Answer (score 0):

isn't each file in its own buffer and you can yank the text while buffer 1 is active then switch to buffer 2 and do the put?
Btw, stop using vi and switch to vim (you may already be using vim as on some linux distros i'm pretty sure that 'vi' is just a link to 'vim').
In Vim you can actually split the screen and see both buffers at the same time.

Comment: " you can yank the text while buffer 1 is active then switch to buffer 2 and do the put?" -> That's what, how to do it?